# Starting with SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee

I am planning to start developing a Web Application, it's my first contact with J2EE (i used to develop standard Java Applications), the problem is that i must use SpringMVC for this project, this is a constraint ...
Since i am a newbie to Enterprise Web Development, i don't know if it's logical idea to start directly learning the Model-View-Controller Architecture! i am looking for suggestions and opinions regarding what to start with, a brief explanation or any helpful ideas are very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cool thing about Spring ( including SpringMVC ), it'll teach you many things along the way.

Interesting difference with some other techs => Spring 99.9% will teach you awesome patterns as well.

Go with [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), don't be afraid of not getting something. There are Spring Forum, SO, Google.. etc. You'll be fine :)

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement :)

Answer (score 1):

I would follow [that tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/), it's quite well done and cover pretty much every aspect of Spring MVC

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my point is: can i start with SpringMVC directly regardless any prior knowledge related to other architectures?

Comment: If you have any experience with web development, I'd say yes. Spring MVC has some strange concepts that can take a while to fully grasp (fields binding, etc.) but it doesn't require any prior experience in "EE" development. Also, if you're familiar with Spring paradigms (prototypes, annotations) it helps

Comment: I have just finished the [Spring MVC Fast Tutorial](http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring). It's quite simple and show's some capabilities of SpringMVC, i am now ready to go forward :)

Comment: Good luck for your experiments :)